# Do I need to fill out the 'receiver' info in AndroidManifest.xml if I register a BroadcastReceiver dynamically?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, dynamically-generated

Do I need to fill out the 'receiver ... /receiver' content in AndroidManifest.xml if I register a BroadcastReceiver dynamically using 'registerReceiver(mReceiver, pIntentFltr)' and unregisterReceiver(mReceiver). It seems like I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need it. The mechanisms complement each other, as stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html):

> There are two ways to make a broadcast receiver known to the system: One is declare it in the manifest file with this element. The other is to create the receiver dynamically in code and register it with the `Context.registerReceiver()` method